# Permissions error on Facebook JS API for comments, even though I have the auths

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-comments

I am attempting to POST a comment with the FB JS API.

```
FB.api("/" + myFBPageId + "/comments", "post", {
  "fb:explicitly_share": true
  "message": contents
}, function(response) { console.log(response) })
```

Unfortunately, even though I have the both publish_actions and publish_stream permissions, I get this exception:

```
"message":"(#200) Permissions error","type":"OAuthException","code":200
```

Um, what? Why? I have tested and I am authed with FB on the site.  I just double checked with this:

```
FB.login(function(response) {
  console.log(response);
}, {scope: 'publish_stream'});
```

So my question is, what is the permissions error here? How do I fix it?

Comment: Could you try the same in graph api explorer?

Comment: @Shadowfax all it says is { "error": "Request failed" }

Comment: Are you authenticated in Facebook OR in your application via facebook OAuth?

Answer (score 2):

> I am attempting to POST a comment

you are just giving the page id. How would the facebook know that to which feed, it should comment? So, you should provide facebook the feed-id instead of the page where you wan t tp post a comment. Here's the correct syntax if you want to **post comment on a feed**:

`/POST_ID/comments`, instead of  `/PAGE_ID/comments`

---

And, if you meant to **post a feed** instead of a comment, you should use-

`/PAGE_ID/feed`

Comment: What does "post a feed" mean?  I think you are probably correct. My intention is that when somebody posts on my page, for it to get shared on Facebook as "X posted a comment on [this website page]" and show up in their/friends news feed.

Comment: So the comment is no where in yoir picture. What exactly you want to do pls elaborate with example (if you are still stucked up with something)